# how to play the 30 seconds sample itunes music

Tags: iphone, android, itunes

I'm trying to figure out if its possible for programmers to build an itunes client app for iphone or android where the user has the option to browse and listen to the song preview, something similar to this page: [itunes link maker](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?playlistId=114688)

I greatly appreciate any pointers or links in this direction

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine your main problem is going to be legal rather than technical.  [The Apple Website's terms of use](http://www.apple.com/legal/terms/site.html) say:

> Except as expressly provided in these Terms of Use, no part of the Site and no Content may be copied, reproduced, republished, uploaded, posted, publicly displayed, encoded, translated, transmitted or distributed in any way (including “mirroring”) to any other computer, server, Web site or other medium for publication or distribution or for any commercial enterprise, without Apple’s express prior written consent.

I'd be surprised if an iTunes Store Browser application passed Apple's approval process since the iPhone already has one and it's even more unlikely that Apple would let you use their content for an Android application.

Comment: I agree, even if it were possible, it's definitely not legal.

Comment: You discount the possibility that @sai can receive Apple's express prior written consent?

Comment: @Graham Lee - Yes, for the reasons given in my post.  Apple would not approve an iPhone App which duplicates their own iTunes Store App and they'd never give permission to use their content for an Android app, since Android is a direct competitor to the iPhone.

Comment: Of course it would make it into the Android Market, as there's no approval. However, it's still exceptionaly unlikely that Apple would give consent that would enable such an app to exist in the first place.

Comment: I can't see why Apple would care about about an Android app doing this.  There are MediaCenter plugins for doing the same kind of thing with movie trailers from iTunes, so why not something similar for Android?

Comment: Apple have just taken HTC to court claiming patent violations which does seem to be a direct public attack on Android.  I would be very surprised if they allowed an "iTunes on Android" app to be created since Apple present iTunes as one of the big benefits of the iPhone.  Similarly, Apple kept updating the iTunes application to prevent it syncing with the Palm Pre.  It seems pretty clear Apple are not keen on their software and services working on competing phones, which is fair enough.  iTunes is their music store and us Android uses will just have to use a different one.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?limit=500&offset=0&term=crowded%20house&attribute=artistTerm&entity=musicTrack&country=GB).

You'll notice that there is a field called "previewUrl".  This gives the url to direct to for the preview of the song.  It's not hard to play around with the link to generate content for whatever you're looking for.  Make sure you've got an affiliate license first.....  May as well make money out of any purchases.